# iframe weirdness

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, height

I have two sites that I am sort of melding together. I'm using and iframe to display content from one page in the other as if it were all one site. The caveat here is that I need the page to display as normal when viewed in an iframe and to display a warning otherwise. I cannot import the iframe page into the host page due to IIS incompatibility so that option is out. The plan works fine when I simply display the page under all circumstances, it is when I try to implement the conditional display that I run into problems. On the iframe page I have the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function InFrame() {
        MainContent_siteIsNotFramed
        if (top != self) {
            //document.getElementById("siteIsFramed").style.display = "inline"
            siteIsFramed.visible = "true"
        }
        else {
            //document.getElementById("MainContent_siteIsNotFramed").style.display = "inline"
            siteIsNotFramed.visible = "true"
        }
        init();
    };
</script>
```

This is my attempt to get the iframe page to handle its own conditional display. The only relevant code I have in the host page is the iframe itself which, for completelness, looks like this:

```
</head>
<body style="margin:0; height: 100%;">

<iframe  runat="server" id="signInFrame" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
    Your browser does not support iframes. Consider upgrading.
</iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

When the content to display/not display, the content in the iframe will display with about half height. Without, it displays at full height (desired behavior). I've tried to be as thourough as possible, if anyone needs more details, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "positioning" the iframe:

```
<iframe  runat="server" id="signInFrame" style="border: 0; position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
   Your browser does not support iframes. Consider upgrading.
</iframe>
```

The problem is that and iframe with default position (position: static) can't have a "relative" height (i.e. a %), so it ignores the height:100%, and applies the "default" height of an iframe (150px in FF).

Comment: That's not working either. I can't seem to figure out if the problem is with the iframe or with the div I'm trying to show/hide in the iframe page.

Comment: I've decided to simply redirect to an error page when the site is not displayed in an iframe rather than showing/hiding two divs. Without the wrapping div, the page displays just fine in an iframe. Thanks for the help though.